# Uncaught TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom 5.3.0. I wanted to try out new hooks approach but I am getting an error saying
`Uncaught TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined`

I have a component BasicRouting as below:

```
import {React} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Link, useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicRouting() {
  let home = useRouteMatch("/");
  let about = useRouteMatch("/about");
  let users = useRouteMatch("/users");
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        {home && <Home match={home}/>}
        {about && <About match={about}/>}
        {users && <Users match={users}/>}
      </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

And index.js as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import BasicRouting from './BasicRouting';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    < BasicRouting/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

How to solve this error and is this the correct way to use `useRouteMatch` hook

Comment: The `Router` needs to wrap the *entire* app or ReactTree that needs the routing context. Move the `Router` component *outside* `App` so the `useRouteMatch` hook has a routing context higher in the ReactTree.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. That solved my issue I have added my answer after the required changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @matthiasgiger answer I tried some fixes and now my code is working.

Below is the working code

BasicRouting:

```
import {React} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Link, useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicRouting() {
  let home = useRouteMatch({
    path: "/",
    exact: true
  });
  let about = useRouteMatch("/about");
  let users = useRouteMatch("/users");
  return (
    
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        
        {about && <About match={about}/>}
        {users && <Users match={users}/>}
        {home && <Home match={home}/>}
      </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

index

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import BasicRouting from './BasicRouting';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    < BasicRouting/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with `useRouteMatch` which requires the Router context (which in your case is defined in the same component and therefore not accessible).

Instead of `useRouteMatch` try the following:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about">
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Users />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Check out the `react-router` for a more detailed [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

Comment: Actually, I am trying to learn useRouteMatch hook and documentation isn't clear on that